# Javascript error where it should run fine

Tags: javascript, variables, error-handling, expression

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error in my javascript file?

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myContent',[]);

app.controller('ContentController',function($scope) {

    $scope.filtered = [];

    $scope.img=[
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top1.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top2.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top3.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top4.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe1.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe2.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe3.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe4.jpg', link:'https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/tops-1/products/la-bella-top-white'}
    ];

    $scope.getData = function(value){
        $scope.filtered = $scope.img.filter(test=>test.id == value);

    }

});

})();
```

The issue is found with this line right here :

```
 $scope.filtered = $scope.img.filter(test=>test.id == value);
```

The errors I am getting are "variable test implicitly declared" and "expression expected"

Comment: You have a typo in declaration : $scope.filteted = []; you write filteted

Comment: where test variable is declared?

Comment: @Pascalz you are right, i uploaded an old copy of my code. I just edited it with the current version I am working on and I still get the error I mentioned before

Comment: @Kurohige its not, I was under the assumption that it was a placeholder variable?

Comment: this code worked fine for me. Do you get the same error when you replace test inside filter to something else

Comment: @JarekKulikowski that is so weird, my images will not show up when I click the list item with the same id as the specified one. and yes

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Linter? Browser console? What browser/version?

Comment: I guess you are using ids for grouping when you display a view.  I usually break the array up in to object for this purpose in Angular, as in $scope.img = {SHOES: [], TOPS: []}, but that's just my preference.  I find it easier to handle in ng-repeat.

Comment: Most likely your AngularJS version doesn't support the use of arrow functions. use the less fancy way `function(test){return test.id == value}`